# CASE WHEN with date and empty values

Tags: mysql, date, case

A have a following piece of code:

```
case when m.mwid like '%NWLY_DAI%' then m.action_date
else ''
end 'Data MWID'
```

The result does not return date, but string (it's shown in green and not in redbrownish as other dates are).

Any ideas how to make it return date? What with '' values tough??

Comment: `else NULL` instead of `''` ? - CASE must return a single type only.

Comment: That did the trick!